# howto remote debug server code on meteor?

Tags: node.js, debugging, meteor, node-inspector

When i start my Server with:

```
 ROOT_URL="http://myserver:24000" meteor debug --settings config/settings.json --port 24000 --inspect
```

i get the cosole log:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/a540a686-0a99-4a2a-ae85-bf06f74bc274
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

But when i try to access http://myserver:9229/a540a686-0a99-4a2a-ae85-bf06f74bc274 i get site is not available....

I am using:

```
Meteor v1.8.0.2
Node: v8.11.4
```

**NOTE:**
I want to remote debug, i am not on the same machine where my meteor app is running.

Answer (score 2):

To remote debug your Meteor app you now can just [use the node internal inspector](https://docs.meteor.com/commandline.html#meteordebug) and omit the `debug` command:

```
ROOT_URL="http://myserver:24000" meteor --inspect --settings config/settings.json --port 24000
```

which now runs your Meteor app as usual with public port 24000. Now the console should show you the following output:

```
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
W20190218-21:01:14.539(1)? (STDERR) Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/2ee5da2d-c15b-416a-9efc-a19bb1299f35
W20190218-21:01:14.552(1)? (STDERR) For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
=> Started your app.

=> App running at: http://myserver:24000/
```

In order to remote debug your server-side code you need a [node inspector client](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/#inspector-clients) to attach to `ws://127.0.0.1:9229/2ee5da2d-c15b-416a-9efc-a19bb1299f35` which is a websocket-based location and cannot be used via `http://...`.

If you use chrome you can just enter `chrome://inspect` and look in the list of `Remote Target` where there should be an entry with your Meteor app `Target (v8.11.4)` (which is the internal `node` version of Meteor 1.8.0.2). Click on `inspect` and the console should now print

```
W20190218-21:08:48.039(1)? (STDERR) Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/2ee5da2d-c15b-416a-9efc-a19bb1299f35 W20190218-21:08:48.040(1)? (STDERR) For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector W20190218-21:08:49.291(1)? (STDERR) Debugger attached.
```

Now open your app in another tab or browser window via `http://myserver:24000/` and use it until the `debugger` breakpoints on the server side code is triggered and watch the inspector tab switch to debugging mode (as you may already know from client debugging).

Answer (score 0):

I found the Problem, i have not added a host to the `--inspect` parameter.
Now its working by adding `--inspect=0.0.0.0:9229`